# How to set the theme for the whole app on a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-theme

How do I set the app theme on a fragment: This is what I came up with so far:

```java
public class settings_fragment extends Fragment {
    Switch switch1;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_fragment,container,false);

        switch1 = view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        //check if theme is in dark mode or not
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES){
            setTheme //This gives me an error, but it would work if it wasn't on a fragment
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call getActivity().setTheme()  and then getActivity. recreate, but your fragment will be recreated also. So I think what you need is to set that check in your container activity onCreate method before super call.